# Manage memory in java

Tags: java, memory-management

In Java, we create an object from a class, And the class is in the heap memory,

How can this class be cleared of this memory after the completion of the task?

Looking for a command or code, or whatever, to control the memory occupied by Java and empty it if necessary.

Thank.

Comment: Are you asking about the memory occupied by the object, or the memory occupied by the class?

Comment: yes,I want to empty this memory after work

Comment: Yes, do you want to empty the memory occupied by the object?  Or do you want to empty the memory occupied by the class?  Or do you not understand the difference?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I also want to remove that class from memory after class completion, and I also want to empty memory if necessary.

Comment: I would like to use both of them if necessary

Comment: What do you mean by "after class completion"?  Anyway, if you really want to expel loaded classes from memory, you'd have to write  your own ClassLoader implementation.  This is a huge subject, and a bit too broad to be answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I mean, we use the class and we no longer need it. In relation to ClassLoader, please explain a bit to search on Google to learn this.